# Converting a string datetime with timezone to a GMT datetime variable

Tags: string, sql-server-2008, timezone

I have a string that contains a date time value with a timezone that I need to convert to a datetime variable.

My string looks like `2012/01/11 06:38:00.00 EST`

Not all of the times are in EST so I cannot just hardcode the offset.  Is there a function that can take the entire string and convert it to GMT?

I am working in SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

Strings like "EST" do not offer enough information to know what the timezone is. For example, timezones America/Montreal and Australia/Sydney both use the marker "EST".

If you can make some assumptions about your data, you will probably just have to build yourself a mapping between timezone tags like "EST" and what offset they translate to. Then it becomes a matter of parsing the time string with `strptime()` or the like. (I'm sure you would prefer to do this in a programming language other than SQL!)